# Tankless water heater dims lights, interrupts the internet and caused static on the radio

Tags: electrical

I recently replaced my Rheem RTE13kw tankless water heater with the newer version of the same heater(RTEX13KW).  The new water heater causes a group of wall lights that are all on the same switch to dim...no other lights in the house are affected.  While the water heater is running the internet will not work at all, and the radio will have a lot of static.  The old water heater never had these issues.  The lights dim the worst when the water is on low and when only the #1 heating element is on. With the water on high the lights seem fine, but the internet still doesn't work.  I have run all the diagnostics on the heater that Rheem provides in the troubleshooting guide and I have found no issues with the water heater.  If there is anybody that can give me some ideas it would be very helpful.

Comment: Get a multimeter. Check voltage on 120V (**both** sides/poles/legs, if you can figure out what's what) and 240V circuits when the heater is off, running "water is on low" and any other modes. That way we can see if this is a "simple" voltage drop or if there is possibly something more serious (e.g., a neutral problem) going on.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact -- I doubt it's anything load-related because the old water heater was also a tankless, apparently of the same rating?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel You may be right. But sometimes things get a bit "confused" during installation. Easy enough to check.

Comment: I did check the voltage coming in, together they were 242V...I did not check them individually. The voltage on the heating elements when the water was running is 237V on both of them. Both heating elements had 9.7 ohms, the speck is between 6 and 10 ohms. I am not sure what you mean by a neutral problem...there are only two wires(120V each) and a bare ground going into the heater. That wire was factory installed and came with the heator.  I wired that wire directly to my breaker box with a 2 poll 60A breaker. I know it should have its own box but that is how the original water heater was wired

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact -- yeah, it's definitely not neutral, as a tankless WH is 240V-only.  The radio static makes me think EMI....

Comment: Can you tell us how your Internet service is set up? Also is the radio that goes staticky battery-powered or mains-powered?

Comment: Yes they were basically the same water heater (13 kw).  I don't have an amp meter, but would it do me any good to check the amp draw on the heating elements?

Comment: It's a wire connection problem. Weeza need some photos.

Comment: The internet is dsl. the radio is plugged in to a wall outlet.  All of the issues, lights, internet and radio are on the same side of the house as the water heater, but I am not sure if and how that matters,

Comment: 242 off, 237 on is a minor drop and it does sound like neutral should not be involved. All the numbers basically add up for 13kW, 60A breaker. Wired to its own box vs. 2-pole breaker in your main box shouldn't matter. So that leaves either a faulty heater causing interference or a strange wiring problem.

Comment: Is this water heater powered by a sub panel? The voltages appear normal I would want L1 to ground and L2 to ground both with the water flowing and not flowing (both hot to ground)  dim lights may signal a bad connection electrical noise the same it could be something was knocked loose when the new heater was installed.

Comment: At 240v and 9.7 ohm elements, they should be drawing about 24-25 amps each.  If you have access to an "amp clamp" type meter, double check that AND check to make sure you have zero amps on the ground wire. The heater may have a ground fault.  What else is "new" besides the water heater? New wiring, breaker?

Comment: Hi Ed, the water heater is not powered by a sub panel...it is wired directly into the main with a 2 poll 60A breaker.  I was not 100% sure what you were asking me to measure, so here is what I did.  I first checked the voltage at the breaker.  it was 120 on both sides, next I followed the wire to the connection in the water heater, it was 119V or 120V on both sides.  Next I checked the terminals on the top of the heating elements, they were about 117V or 118V.   Next I checked the voltage with the water running, it was about 116V or 117V on the terminals on top of the heating elements.

Comment: All of those measurements were with one probe on ground and the other probe on power.  I did also try one other test, I plugged the internet modem into a 100ft cord and plugged it into an outlet on the other side of the room...that fixed the problem with the internet, but I am not sure what that test proved.

Comment: Hi George, I think I will buy an amp meter.  I was going to try to use my meter to check the ground wire for amperage, but I decided it wasn't worth possibly smoking it.  The water heater is the only new electrical Item in the house.

Comment: You'd have to disconnect the ground wire to test it with your current meter and that's NOT something you want to do for a couple of reasons, one you mentioned, and the other it's dangerous. If you did indeed have a GF with metal pipe you could electrify your entire plumbing system. NOT SAFE. .  An amp-clamp meter is very handy and even moderately priced ones are very accurate. ...also handy to have in the future.   Having a ground fault on a new WH is unlikely, but you have an odd problem.

Comment: Arcing to ground might explain static on radio. Lights dimming might be due to 54 A current pulling down the voltage at the service entry.